# Mid 2010 MacBook Dualbooting OSX & Elementary OS Sound Issue

Tags: macbook, audio

Please check out this short video I just posted regarding the issue I’m experiencing.

https://youtu.be/2mpzK64W1TM

As you can see the audio is terribly distorted and only plays out of the left side. I’m dual booting both OS using rEFInd and the audio in OSX plays normally as it always did before.

Any ideas why I may be experiencing this? Thanks!